# Defining a function in R and drawing its plot

Tags: r

I need to define the following function and need to plot a graph for it in R.

```
0 <= x <= 975    f(x)=975
975 < x <= 1025  f(x)=x
1025 < x         f(x) = 1025
```

I tried to define it the following way, but it gives me syntax errors -

```
myfunc <- function() 
{
if (xx <= 975) 
{return(975)} 
else if (xx < 975 and xx <= 1025)
{return(xx)}
else {return (1025)}
}
```

I was referring to below page for syntax.
http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-chain-if133else-statements-in-r.html

After defining the function, I wish to plot it. Will the below command work ?

```
curve(expr=myfunc,from=0,to=1100,xlim=c(0,1100),ylim=c(0,1100),xlab="",ylab="")
```

Kindly let me know if I need to provide any further information.

Comment: The 5th line should be `else if(975 < xx & xx <= 1025)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&` has already been pointed out to you. Your function also needs an argument and it needs to be vectorized to work with `curve`. You can achieve vectorization by using `ifelse` instead of `if` and `else`. However, I believe the following is nicer:

```
myfunc <- function(x) {
  #find the intervals in which each value is
  interv <- as.integer(cut(x, c(0,975,1025,Inf),include.lowest = TRUE))
  #in arithmetic operations logical values TRUE/FALSE are coerced to 1/0
  (interv==1L)*975 + (interv==2L)*x + (interv==3L)*1025
}

#note the n=1e3 which achieves a better resolution of the curve
curve(expr=myfunc,from=0,to=1100,
         xlim=c(0,1100),ylim=c(0,1100),xlab="",ylab="", n=1e3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Roland for the information and letting me know of the cut function.
Coming to Ifelse, I believe i can use it only for one condition and not multiple of them i.e. i can only specify if x < 975 and action depending on the value of x. Because as per it's syntax, first we specify test condition and then specify the values it should return if the condition is true or false. 

Let me know if my understanding is incorrect.

Thanks!!

Comment: You can nest `ifelse` just like `if` and `else`. There should be many examples on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because boolean AND is not written as "and" but as "&":

`else if (xx < 975 & xx <= 1025)`

Apart from that you mean:

`else if (xx > 975 and xx <= 1025)`

And also you should provide the function your argument:

`myfunc <- function(xx)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the total solution you are looking for:

```
myfunc <- Vectorize(function(xx) {
  if (xx <= 975){
    return(975)
  } else if (xx > 975 && xx <= 1025){
    return(xx)
  } else {
    return (1025)
  }
})

curve(myfunc, 0, 1100, xlim=c(0,1100), ylim=c(0,1100), xlab="", ylab="")
```